# Display DIV after 1 link and 1 other DIV are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

What I am trying to accomplish is having a div displayed after some one clicks on the twitter share button and the facebook share button.

Here is the code I have tried so far for making the div enabled after just the facebook button is clicked.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>


<a id="t" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://google.com" data-text="Testing Tweet Buttons">Tweet</a>
<br>
<div id="f" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://google.com" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" ></div>
<br>
<div id="done" style="display:none;">Thanks!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#f").click(function () {
            $("#done").toggle("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. Seems it works, just your FB div sort of dissapears (and it's hard to click a box with 0 width). I've added 5px red border to it and it works for me.

Also, I've added the line including jQuery itself. Maybe that is what you've forgotten to do :>

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gcn8gkhn/

And here's the code:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<a id="t" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://google.com" data-text="Testing Tweet Buttons">Tweet</a>
<br>
<div id="f" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://google.com" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" >Facebook button</div>
<br>
<div id="done" style="display:none;">Thanks!</div>

<style>
#f{
   border:5px solid red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f").click(function(){
        $("#done").toggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this is the div only shows after you click on the red border and not actual facebook button.  http://puu.sh/bZmjU/718a7c8075.png

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. You can use two variables to mark the clicks. Please refer to the code below :-

```
var fClick=false; // Initially false
var tClick=false; // Initially false
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#f").click(function () {
            fClick=true;// Make fClick truye and check if both were pressed
            if(fClick&&tClick)
                $("#done").show("slow");
        });

        $("#t").click(function () {
            tClick=true;
            if(fClick&&tClick)
                $("#done").show("slow");// Make tClick truye and check if both were pressed
    });
});
```

Here is a working example of the same :- http://jsfiddle.net/hy8mmpeo/

Comment: Thanks, this works in theory and in jsfiddle.  However, when I use it with the actual facebook and twitter buttons it does not work unfortunately.  I will let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: can you share the console log ? there must be a reason for it not to work ?